# Same URL for different rutes expression in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-2

How use same url for different rutes expression in codeigniter.
For exemple, to use "x" like any word in my code and always to result in same url?

```
$route['list'] ='x/list';
```

Url expected: mysite.com/list

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a value for x as `$x = "http://www.example.com";` then use it like this `$route['list'] ='$x/list';` but you may need to revise the `$route['']` variable name `list`, view example on https://www.javatpoint.com/codeigniter-url-routing